# flutter firebase offline error caused by sending get request to real time database

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

im currently trying to use flutter and firebase realtime database together but i keep on getting this error whenever i try and get or update the database. it was working fine a few days ago but i accidently rolled back the changes.

i have done

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "main_app",
    options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "fXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        measurementId: "XXXXX"
    )
  );
```

the error occurs wheneever i do
`FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("/users").get()`
i have tried different end points to check if that is the problem but the error is hard to understand imo

```java
I/RepoOperation( 6096): get for query / falling back to disk cache after error: Client is offline
E/firebase_database( 6096): An unknown error occurred handling native method call Query#get
E/firebase_database( 6096): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: Client is offline
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabasePlugin.lambda$queryGet$8$FirebaseDatabasePlugin(FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java:248)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.-$$Lambda$FirebaseDatabasePlugin$zohedUhq4ZX8w6dhHgizPHWixGY.call(Unknown Source:4)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
E/firebase_database( 6096): Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Client is offline
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.lambda$get$1$PersistentConnectionImpl(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:441)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at com.google.firebase.database.connection.-$$Lambda$PersistentConnectionImpl$DHovbqW2nxPacSd_wNZBtpYapws.run(Unknown Source:8)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
E/firebase_database( 6096):     ... 3 more
E/flutter ( 6096): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(94)] Dart Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/unknown] java.lang.Exception: Client is offline
E/flutter ( 6096): 
E/flutter ( 6096): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 6096): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 6096): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6096): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:367:43)
E/flutter ( 6096): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6096): #3      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:74:22)
E/flutter ( 6096): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6096): #4      Query.get (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:21:27)
E/flutter ( 6096): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6096): , stack trace: #0      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 6096): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6096): #1      Query.get (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:21:27)
E/flutter ( 6096): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6096):
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling `get()`, while you're offline and with no data in the cache.

Keep in mind you have to explicitly enable disk persistence for the Firebase Realtime Database before it can read data from it while you're offline. You can do this by calling [`setPersistenceEnabled(true)`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/setPersistenceEnabled.html) at the start of the app, before calling any methods that read/write data:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: one of my problems is is that the client is online. im currently using my phone on debug mode to test my applications with wifi on and everything. tbh idk what to do because it is all fine untill you try and request data and im asuming because it was unable to grab the data from cache, it checks online but it doesnt think it is online or smth.

Comment: I took a guess at what the problem is, as it's impossible to be certain without a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run. If my answer in its current form doesn't help you solve the problem, please edit your question to show such a minimal repro.

Comment: dw just solved. it

Comment: Good to her @scebab  --- Could you write up your solution in an answer, so others can benefit from it?

Comment: i simply created a new Firebase app from scratch, used the android xml and edited everything shown on the firebase website. somehow it worked the next time when i added this once and them removed it :/

Answer (score 0):

What I did and it worked for me. Just

1. flutter pub clean.
2. uninstall the app on your device.
3. flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

I have just set read and write permissions to true in Realtime database rules and it worked for me.